# Calibration error in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, calibration

I'm programming with OpenCV and now I'm exactly at the point in which I need to calibrate the camera. I've found some tips of the already implemented code in the samples folder of OpenCV, but when I build it, record some images and try to calibrate the camera, appears the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.size == dst.size && src.channels()
== dst.ch annels()) in cvConvertScale, file C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\o
pencv\modules\core\src\convert.cpp, line 6213
```

I've thought that problem could be that the photos are actually not good enough and the matrix used to find the parameters of the camera would be ill-conditioned. But I'm not quite sure with it's the problem. Have you already faced with this problem before? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You should try to debug to the point that this error is and show that part of the code. Assuming the code is correct however, you can check to make sure that the correct amount of corners are being detected, sometimes this can throw off the calibration.

Comment: I've found thoretically where the problem is. At the line 302 comes the following code:

found = findChessboardCorners(arguments);

which I've substituted the real arguments with the same name to be not so polluted. They are: view, s.boardSize, CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK    | CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE
What nothing less than the function to identification of the chessboard is